# Copying data from one table to another using parameters

Tags: sql-server, select, parameters, insert

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another using global parameters to define the local parameters.  The string values for the local parameters is changed appropriately, however, when I try to use them as the referenced column names it populates the column I am trying to colpy to with just the value of the parameter and not the values from the columns of the other table.  I'm new to sql so I am stuck.

```
DECLARE @ProductName VarChar(255), @SiteName VarChar(255)

SET @ProductName =
    CASE @@[Level]
        WHEN 1 THEN 'MaterialAggName'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'TradeAggName'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'ProfitCenterAggName'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'PerformanceCenterAggName'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'ValueCenterAggName'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'BusinessAggName'
    END;

SET @SiteName =
    CASE @@[CustomerLevel] 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Customer_Postal_Name'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Customer_3DigitPostal_Name'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Customer_Location_Name'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Customer_Region_Name'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Customer_County_Name'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Customer_GeoBusiness_Name'
    END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp_Demand]
(
SiteName VarChar(255),
ProductName VarChar(255),
Quantity Int
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Temp_Demand] (SiteName, ProductName, Quantity)
SELECT @SiteName, @ProductName, Final
FROM   [dbo].[Customers_Master]
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: what is `@@[Level]` and `@@[CustomerLevel]`

Comment: As posted your question doesn't make much sense. You might take a look at this article to get started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You need to use "Dynamic SQL" to use variables for column names.   Google and learn about Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use Dynamic SQL, your insert statement would need something like .

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

Set @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Temp_Demand] (SiteName, ProductName, Quantity)
SELECT ''' + @SiteName + ''', ''' + @ProductName + ''', Final
FROM   [dbo].[Customers_Master]'

sp_executesql @SQL
```

If there is more than one insert with changing values, simply put this in a loop. *except the declare of course.